# realtime.co xRTML client - Make client stay connected, not to Auto Disconnect and Reconnect

Tags: javascript, push-notification, real-time

I am using [realtime.co xRTML](http://docs.xrtml.org/xrtml/javascript/3-2-0/xrtml.connectionmanager.connection.html) for a real time app.  I use it in a chat application in a Hybrid mobile app. The client disconnects and reconnects every minute (sometimes 30 seconds or so).

I want to know how can I set the client to stay connected (not disconnect), so I can handle the connection myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your device is disconnecting from the internet/network. Realtime/xRTML doesn't disconnect by itself.